# ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_proces s_ske_dhe:dh key too small

Tags: mysql, openssl, rhel

I am getting this error when using this command:

```
ssldir=/home/inet/devel/config/mysql_ssl

mysql \
        -vvvvv \
        -u ***** \
        -p \
        -h eos3 \
        --ssl-ca $ssldir/cacert.pem \
        --ssl-cert $ssldir/server-cert.pem \
        --ssl-key $ssldir/server-key.pem
```

The eos3 server is on RHEL6, openssl-1.0.1e-fips MySQL 5.1.73

I have 3 other servers I am trying to make the connection from

- A) RHEL7 mariadb-5.5.68, openssl-1.0.2k-fips
- B) RHEL8 MySQL 8.0.26, openssl-1.1.1k  FIPS
- C) RHEL9 mariadb-10.5.16, openssl-3.0.1

A and C have no problem connecting, B does, and if I try MySQL 8.0.30 on RHEL9 it also fails

I am really trying to solve an issue with PHP 8.0 not being able to make an SSL connection to eos3.

I have read a number of posts that say to try relaxing a setting in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`, but none of my servers have that file, it is in `/etc/pki/tls` instead.  Making this change there didn't help.

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

The cipherlist returned by EOS3 when making a MySQL SSL connection is:

```
| Ssl_cipher_list | ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:EC
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA
-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-S
HA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELL
IA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-G
CM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:EC
DH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:P
SK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH
E-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-A
ES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA
:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES12
8-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES1
28- |
```

As far as I can tell my certificate and RSA keys are 2048 bit.  Didn't work when I had 1024 bit ones as the documentation says.

When I do get an SSL connection, the `Ssl_version` is always `TLSv1.2`, which I expect.
The Ssl Cipher is different between RHEL7 connection and the RHEL9 connection

```
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   AES256-GCM-SHA384  respectively.
```

Why would MariaDB work, but not MySQL?  I am hoping if I can get MySQL to work, then PHP would have a better chance of working.  Using `PEAR.php`, `DB.php` and `mysqli_d.php` within PHP.

Comment: `The eos3 server is on RHEL6, openssl-1.0.1e-fips MySQL 5.1.73`. RHEL6 eoled in 2020,  OpenSSL 1.0.2 LTS eoled in 2019 (1.0.1 way before), , MySQL 5.1 eoled *10 years ago* in 2013.

Comment: Unfortunately we have 500+ systems on RHEL6, MySQL 5.1.69.  Upgrading them all to RHEL8/RHEL9 is not an option at this time.  If mariadb mysql command line can make a secure connection, why can't PHP and the MySQL mysql command line.  I have been recently testing PHP and PHP and the MySQL mysql command line, against RHEL7, RHEL8, and RHEL9, from each of those systems to each other, still won't connect with a secure connection, only the mariadb mysql command line will connect.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that your server is configured with a too small DH (Diffie-Hellman) key, which is considered unsecure by recent TLS libraries.

MySQL 5.1 uses a 512 bit DH key, MySQL 5.7 uses a 2048- bit key: (see this [commit](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/commit/866b988a76e8e7e217017a7883a52a12ec5024b9))

If you can't upgrade your systems you could try the following:

1. Patch viosslfactories.c and recompile MySQL 5.1
2. Try to specify a cipher suite which doesn't need DH: e.g. AES256-SHA256

Comment: Thanks.  Specifying to use AES256 on the client side fixes the issue.  Odd that the client and server don't negotiate this cipher by default, when all ciphers are allowed, or for instance a DH/DHE cipher is listed before AES256 in the cipher_list passed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `TLS.MinProtocol = TLSv1` on `RHEL9` to `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf` as shown below fixes the problem with `MySQL 8.26/8.30`

```
[ crypto_policy ]
.include = /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config

# allow mysql command line (et al) to talk to older servers
TLS.MinProtocol = TLSv1
```

This doesn't help with `PHP`, only specifying a cipher list that doesn't include the DH/DHE ciphers to `mysqli_set_ssl` fixed the issue.